# I don't know how to display step 3 for this assignment

Tags: python, list, dictionary

[Click here to see step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIoVr.png)
So far I think am on the right track for steps 1 and 2 but if I can improve it please let me know. For step 3 I have no clue how to display all 20 rows, if they are reserve or unreserved, and the names of the input users.

```
reserveDict = {}



def reserve():

  global reserveDict


  tablenum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  if tablenum not in reserveDict.keys():
    name = input("Table is avaiable, please enter your name: ")
    reserveDict[tablenum] = name 
  else:
    print("Table is unavaiable")



def remove():
  global tablenum

  tablenum = int(input("Enter the table number: "))





 del reserveDict[tablenum]

def report():
  global reserveDict



 count = len(reserveDict)






while(True):
 print("1- Reserve a Table")
 print("2- Clear Reservation")
 print("3- Report")
 print("0- Exit")

choice = int(input("Choose a option "))

if choice == 1:
    reserve()

elif choice == 2:
    remove()
```

Comment: General tip: use global variables sparingly. They seem unnecessary here, you could easily have your functions operate on their arguments only.

Comment: @speedx1 if you find your solution, you should vote and put the "Green tick". It's your civic duty to this platform :)

Answer (score -1):

I didn't improve your step 1 , 2. I just built your step 3 and 4. Here is the entire code..

```
reserveDict = {}



def reserve():

  global reserveDict
  tablenum = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  if tablenum not in reserveDict.keys():
    name = input("Table is avaiable, please enter your name: ")
    reserveDict[tablenum] = name 
  else:
    print("Table is unavaiable")



def remove():
  global tablenum
  tablenum = int(input("Enter the table number: "))
  del reserveDict[tablenum]

def report():
  global reserveDict
  for i in range(20):
      if i in reserveDict.keys():
          print(i,reserveDict[i])
      else:
          print(i,"available")







while(True):
    print("1- Reserve a Table")
    print("2- Clear Reservation")
    print("3- Report")
    print("0- Exit")

    choice = int(input("Choose a option "))

    if choice == 1:
        reserve()

    elif choice == 2:
        remove()
    elif choice == 3:
        report()
    elif choice == 0:
        exit()
```

Comment: @AlexanderCécile please click on the "click here to see step 3" and see why I should do in that way.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to offer no comments on OP’s current code? The way it’s written means your solution ends up being just bizarre.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile  See again in my post. I said I just built the step 3 and 4. Step 3 means the reserve function. And step 4 means the exit().

Comment: @speedx you are welcome. If you found your solution then please put the green tick in my solution

Comment: @AlexanderCécile that's because it's the questioner task to improve. I think the major problem to the questioner was how to print and what's the way to print.

Comment: @KaziZiaulHassan I didn’t say you should do OP’s work for them, I meant some sort of explanation or advice. In any case, I am working on an answer to do that now so it should be fine in the end.